# Need to update a pandas dataframe row based on cell value. Also, if 2 rows have same cell value, need to update only the first

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

## SCENARIO 1

Dataframe is as follows:

```
   AAA   BBB
0    A   100
1    B   100
2    C   100
3    D   100
```

Set AAA = 'Z' and BBB = 200 where AAA = 'C'?

## SCENARIO 2

Dataframe is as follows:

```
   AAA   BBB
0    A   100
1    B   100
2    C   100
3    B   100
```

Set AAA = 'Z' and BBB = 200 where AAA = 'B' but only where index = 1? So basically only in the first row if multiple rows meet "where" criteria.

## My attempt

I tried something like this and it works for Scenario 1 but I have no idea how to do Scenario 2

```
df.iloc[ np.where( df_positions.AAA == 'C')[0]] = 'Z'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html#pandas-dataframe-idxmax) to get first row index from matches.

```py
df.loc[df.AAA.eq('B').idxmax()] = ['Z', 200]
df
  AAA  BBB
0   A  100
1   Z  200
2   C  100
3   B  100
```

And if you want to replace same value (`['Z',200]`) each time you can do both scenario at once

```py
df.loc[[df.AAA.eq(x).idxmax() for x in ['C','B']]] = ['Z',200]
df
  AAA  BBB
0   A  100
1   Z  200
2   Z  200
3   B  100
```

Comment: Thank you. I will test this out in my scenario.

Answer (score 2):

In your case

```
cond=(df.index==1)&df.AAA.eq('B')
df.loc[cond]=['Z',200]
df
  AAA  BBB
0   A  100
1   Z  200
2   C  100
3   B  100
```

Comment: Thank you. But I guess I was not clear about one thing. The dataframe is not constant. I could have same value for AAA in any 2 rows. So I cannot hardcode index = 1. I need to somehow find the 2 rows and then get the minimum of the 2 rows and then the next steps.